# How can i compare nested objects by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object inside nested objects. I want to detect if object name exist, get text value of this object
I try to reach by for loop inside element. But i can reach only one step.

```
var data = [
  { "option1": "selectedoption1" },
  { "option2": "selectedoption2" },
  { "option2": "selectedoption3" },
  { "option2": "selectedoption4" }
]
    var selectedOption = jQuery(".option .value").eq(0).text();
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i].selectedOption) {
        console.log(selectedOption);
        // i want to reach  selectedoption1
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your array `data` is broken, are you sure you don't mean: `var data = [{"option1": "selectedoption1"}, { "option2": "selectedoption2" }, { "option2": "selectedoption3" },{"option2": "selectedoption4"}]` ?

Comment: @TehSoTo yes, thank you. I edit to question

Comment: Do all the objects in the array always have just one key/value?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yup !

Comment: [Javascript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) has many methods, of which depending upon browser support needed, `find()` or `filter()` would allow you to see if an element matches.  Otherwise, a loop could be written to test for existance.

Answer (score 1):

Since they all have just one key/value, you can use `find()` and compare it to the first value in `Object.values`

```js
var data = [
    { "option1": "selectedoption1" },
    { "option2": "selectedoption2" },
    { "option2": "selectedoption3" },
    { "option2": "selectedoption4" }
  ]
  
let looking_for = "selectedoption2"
let found = data.find(obj => Object.values(obj)[0] == looking_for) 
console.log(found)

// undefined if value doens't exist:
let not_here = "some_other_value"
found = data.find(obj => Object.values(obj)[0] == not_here) 
console.log(found)
```

Comment: With a note that `find()` only works in MS Edge, not IE.

Comment: `==` should be `===`

Comment: @DanielOrmeño can you offer an example of when you might see a difference between those two comparing strings?

Comment: When working with JS, why asume they will always be strings?

Comment: DanielOrmeño -> Because `jQuery(".option .value").eq(0).text()` but also it's often very useful and probably the correct behavior here to find `1` when you're looking for `"1"`. Nevertheless, point well-taken. It's always a good idea to consider which is best in a given situation.

Comment: Great answer. Thank You ! @MarkMeyer